# ActiveRecord AND + OR condition with multiple criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

I'm using `ActiveRecord` to build a query and I got a parenthesis issue with generated SQL.

Here is a query creating my problem

```
joined_users = User.joins(:consumer)

users = joined_users.where(id: (1..3), name: 'foo').or(joined_users.where(consumer: {id: (1...4))
```

It creates the following SQL

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "consumers" "consumer" ON "consumer"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE ("users"."id" BETWEEN 1 AND 3 AND "users"."name" = 'foo' OR "consumer"."id" >= 1 AND "consumer"."id" < 4)
```

But actually, it should be

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "consumers" "consumer" ON "consumer"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (("users"."id" BETWEEN 1 AND 3 AND "users"."name" = 'foo') OR ("consumer"."id" >= 1 AND "consumer"."id" < 4))
```

Do you get my point?

There are missing parenthesis separating the first `where` to the second with the `or`.

Bool logic is not the same at all with and without these parenthesis.

What am I missing?

Comment: The basic activerecord queries don't do parameter grouping -- you need to use AREL or raw sql.

Answer (score 2):

I your particular case there should be no difference in query result, because logical AND operator has higher priority than logical OR, so:

`A && B || C && D` equals `(A && B) || (C && D)`

ActiveRecord will add parenthesis when it is needed, for example:

```rb
User.where(id: 1..3).or(User.where(id: 4...5)).where(email: 'some')
```

Will result in:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" BETWEEN 1 AND 3 OR "users"."id" >= 4 AND "users"."id" < 5) AND "users"."email" = 'some'
```